# Не фиксированная высота рамок на css

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, svg

Имеется резиновый блок у него не задана высота. Как задать ширину верхнему и нижнему `border`'у в процентном соотношении?
Сделал такой вот `div`

```css
.div {
  background: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.84);
  border-top: 201px solid transparent;
  border-right: 96px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 201px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"> 
</div>
```

Дело в том, что сейчас его высота получается фиксированная из-за высоты рамок и зависит от рамок, а вообще блок сам при уменьшении экрана будет пропорционально уменьшаться, но с высотой рамок не получится этого добиться. Как-то можно это исправить? Чтобы рамки были в процентах от блока.

Может быть можно использовать `before` и `after`, вот только как добиться такого же углубления?

И еще, когда я пытаюсь добавить текст, то он встает по середине блока и увеличивает ему высоту:

```css
.div {
  background: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.84);
  border-top: 201px solid transparent;
  border-right: 96px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 201px solid transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <h1>Привет Привет Привет Привет Привет</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если честно svg прекрасно масштабируется и подойдёт для данной задачи. Можно не задавать явно размеры и использовать свойство `viewBox`. Вынесите это в отдельный файл. Результат:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 30">
  <polygon points="0 0, 100 0, 80 15, 100 30, 0 30" fill="#111" fill-opacity="0.84"></polygon>
</svg>
```

Чтобы увеличить или уменьшить "стрелку" поменяйте значение `80` на большее или меньшее значение.

По умолчанию svg будет пытаться сохранять соотношение сторон, если хотите это отключить (чтобы изображение растягивалось), то добавьте атрибут `preserveAspectRatio="none"` для тэга `svg`.

Результаты с `preserveAspectRatio="none"`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не пойму, как его в div засунуть и как текст туда засунуть?

Comment: @Дима Сохранить весь текст `<svg xmlns…</svg>` как отдельный файл svg (допустим `1.svg`), затем использовать его как картинку (к примеру, `div { background-image: url("1.svg"); }`). Это понятно или надо ещё что пояснить? А текст и любое другое содержимое уже просто как обычный HTML.

Comment: А все понял, спасибо) И во всех браузерах будет отлично работать?

Comment: @Дима Ну у меня даже в IE работает.

Comment: Отлично! Огромное спасибо. Другой свой вариант не удаляйте, буду пробовать все.

Comment: А не подскажите, как сделать еще, наоборот, чтобы этот треугольник углублялся на верхней части div, для мобильных версий div будет именно так. Сейчас он углубляется справа у div. Или может, где почитать подскажите, как эти вершины задавать. Сижу читаю, но не получается:(

Comment: @Дима Да просто немного поиграйтесь с координатами, это несложно. `viewBox="0 0 100 30"` это значит, что у нас есть координаты от `0` до `100` по оси X, и от `0` до `30` по оси Y. Задаётся многоугольник (polygon) с 5ю вершинами (свойство `points`: 1)`0 0`, 2) `100 0`, 3) `80 15`, 4) `100 30`,  5) `0 30`). Нарисуйте это на бумаге, чтобы увидеть и понять, затем попробуйте продумать для мобильной версии другой svg на основе этого. Надо просто этот немного модифицировать. Надеюсь это вам поможет. Но если совсем всё плохо и совсем ничего не получилось, то задайте ещё один вопрос здесь.

Comment: Действительно, получилось, нарисовал график) Вот значения `points="0 0, 50 15, 100 0, 100 30, 0 30"`, спасибо огромное:)

Comment: @Дима Да, это оно, очень рад что получилось.

Answer (score 6):

Вариант с `clip-path`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px 15% 10px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.84);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 85% 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 85% 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  -webkit-clip-path: url("#clipPath");
  clip-path: url("#clipPath");
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  Чтобы рамки были в процентах от блока.
</div>

<div class="div">
  Дело в том, что сейчас его высота получается фиксированная из-за высоты рамок и зависит от рамок, а вообще блок сам при уменьшении экрана будет пропорционально уменьшаться, но с высотой рамок не получится этого добиться. Как-то можно это исправить? Чтобы
  рамки были в процентах от блока.
</div>
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clipPath" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <polygon points="1 0, 0.85 0.5, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Вот это мощь) Спасибо большое, не знал о таком свойстве. А, как для браузеров в наше время? Для старых точно не будет работать скорее всего.

Comment: у ie нет поддержки данного свойства

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Comment: в Сhrome 60.0.3112.78, FF54, Opera 46.0.2597.5, Safari - работает

Comment: А зачем Вы добавили svg? Все же и так работало.

Answer (score 4):

Я вижу, что здесь подойдут градиенты для абсолютно позиционированных элементов. Результат:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.84);
  /* ширина стрелки 50px, смещаемся на такую величину */
  margin-right: 50px;

  /* для вертикального центрирования текста */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* Стили просто для демонстрации */
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  height: 200px;
}

/* псевдоэлементы имитруют половинки "стрелки" */
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  /* ширина стрелки 50px */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, transparent 50%, rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.84) 50%);
}

div:after {
  /* Перевернуть и опустить вниз вторую половинку */
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>Здесь будет некоторый текст</div>
```

Чтобы ширина была нефиксированная, нужно задавать `margin-right` в процентах от ширины, которую нужно вычесть, а для псевдоэлементов `width` в процентах от всей ширины + `margin-right`. Демонстрация:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.84);
  /* ширина стрелки 50px, смещаемся на такую величину */
  margin-right: 20%;

  /* для вертикального центрирования текста */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* Стили просто для демонстрации */
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  height: 200px;
}

/* псевдоэлементы имитруют половинки "стрелки" */
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  /* ширина стрелки 50px */
  width: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, transparent 50%, rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.84) 50%);
}

div:after {
  /* Перевернуть и опустить вниз вторую половинку */
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>Здесь будет некоторый текст</div>
```

Comment: Какой вариант по Вашему мнению лучше мне выбрать из всех предложенных?

Comment: @Дима Если не надо поддерживать IE\Edge, то и `clip-path` можно выбрать. Но если для всех браузеров нужен результат, то однозначно SVG (тем более вариант очень простой, коротенький и тоже легко модифицируется, чтобы увеличить или уменьшить стрелку поменяйте значение 80 на большее или меньшее). Градиенты иногда не особо сглаживаются, поэтому это вариант отметаем.